# Gear Oil HP 85w-140 vs HP-140

Tags: automotive-engineering, gears, transmission

I have a 4 Stroke scooter 150cc (SYM JET-14).
Manufacturer recommends 85w-140 gear oil. The price difference between 85w-140 and single grade 140 is tremendous. Given that in my country and during summer the average temperature is 36°C/97F and it can sometimes reach 42°C/107F, should it really matter winter-viscosity (i.e. 85w)?

Comment: @m.nasim For gearbox oil, a temperature of 40C is just as "stone cold" as 0C. The normal typical operating temperature is likely to be 150 to 200C.

Comment: @m.nasim sometimes manufacturers issue updates/country specific directions (although I doubt that is the case). You can also directly contact the manufacturer and ask them directly about that (if you are lucky you could get sooner an authoritative reply).

Comment: @alephzero Thanks for clarification. I understand that viscosity grade printed on the product matches the operation temperature of gear and/or engine. Really thank you.